# Downcast to template class

Tags: c++, templates, downcast

I've got template class and I wanted to have vector of this class type.
I saw solution where you need to wrap the class with another class without template, and then have a vector of this new class.
Now I want to downcast for example one of the list objects - but the cast not allowed.
What should I do?

Example:

```
class Wrapper
{
}

template <typename T>
class Father : public Wrapper
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Wrapper>> objects;
    Father<int> object = (Father<int>)objects.at(0); // ERROR (lets say i know its integer)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`objects[0]` is a ***pointer*** to an object. Your cast (never use C-style casts by the way) attempts to convert the `shared_ptr<Wrapper>` object to a `Father<int>` object. That's not possible, of course, since those two types are wholly unrelated.

Dereference the pointer and downcast it to a reference (if you want polymorphism):

```
auto& object = static_cast<Father<int>&>(*objects[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap your template class to be able to create a vector with its type.

This will work just fine

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Father<int>>> objects;
std::shared_ptr<Father<int>> object = objects.at(0);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply :)
I wanted vector of some types, not just int